# Extract coefficient from a linear function using regex

Tags: python, regex, linear-algebra, coefficients

I am having this function

x1 +3 x2 +2 x3 -2.2 x4 +19 x5

I need to extract the coefficients [1, 3, 2, -2.2, 19] using regex

I did [^x][1-9] but it is not general. For example if i had

3 x2 -2.2 x41 +19 x50

it will get [3, -2.2, 41, 19, 50] rather than [3, -2.2, 19]

Then I am going to need something to handle this like [^x[1-9][1-9]] but what if i had x124 or x12345 or
n digits after x.

How could I exclude them and get only the coefficients?

Comment: maybe`(?<!x)\d+(\.\d+)?`

Comment: @Eraklon doesn't work for variables. It gets last digits. For example x12 it gets 2, x123 it gets 23 and so on.. However it gets the coefficient

Comment: `(?<!x)\b\d+(\.\d+)?`

Comment: @Certifill are you expecting to get zero for omit power? seems, it's impossible by regex

Comment: @splash58 No. I have another code for that, just the coefficient of the function with the given variables

Comment: @Eraklon The second one worked. Thanks. I could modify it to get the signs

Comment: `{y:(x if x else '+1') for x,y in re.findall(r'([+-]\d*\.{0,1}\d+)?\s*x\s*(\d*)?',s)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

# define the problem
mystring='x1 +3 x2 +2 x3 -2.2 x4 +19 x5'

# get coefficients
regex_coeff='([+-]\d*\.{0,1}\d+) x'

# assuming your polynome is normalized, we can add the one in front
coeffs=[1.0] + [float(x) for x in re.findall(regex_coeff,mystring)]

# get exponents
regex_expo='x(\d+)'
exponents=[int(x) for x in re.findall(regex_expo,mystring)]

# print results
print(coeffs)
print(exponents)

>>[1.0, 3.0, 2.0, -2.2, 19.0]
>>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works and also expands on how to get the exponents. However mine worked without needing the x in the regex_coeff